# Android: Hiding/Unhiding Tab from FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Okay, so I have a FragmentPagerAdapter with 3 pages on it...

Is there a way I can HIDE a page from the SlidingTabLayout? I don't want to destroy the page, as I want to be able to unhide it later. Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to destroy the page, and add it back in later?

Answer (score 1):

Hold all your pages in an `Array` (or a `List`).

```
boolean isHide;

public int getCount (){
    if(isHide){
        return container.size() - 1;
    }
    return container.size();
}

public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   if(isHide && position == positionToHide){
        return container.get(position + 1);
   }
   return container.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to prevent transition to that fragment by hiding the tab button and/or disabling swipe.

fragment will still be loaded but you want be able to move to it.